# How to create an inverse entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I get an error that says:

> the model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store.

I am trying to create an entity: `Category` that has categories and links to different view controllers that contain patterns in the entity: `Clothes`, that relate to the category name.  Am I supposed to make entity: `Category` a parent entity to `Clothes`? When I do this I get an error:

> Category.dateCreated conflicts with a property inherited from Clothes. Both entities contain an attribute named: dateCreated.

Also how would I make the relationship: `clothes` in the `Category` entity = `NSSet`? Ex: @NSManaged `var clothes: NSSet`

/Users/michael/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-03-05 at 10.09.38 AM.png

/Users/michael/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-03-05 at 10.03.29 AM.png

Comment: Your images are not attached to the question. You can edit your question and use the image button at the top of the editor window to attach them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you are seeing is because your Core Data model has changed since you installed the app on the device or simulator. If you delete the app from the device/simulator and run it again, you will not get that error.

Each time you change your model, you will need to delete the app - unless you create model versions and migrate the changes. You shouldn't need to do this until after your app has been released.

If I'm understanding your question, you want the entities `Category` and `Clothes` to have a relationship to each other. Where `Category` can have one or more `Clothes`. You do not need to make `Category` a parent of `Clothes`.

In the Core Data model editor, show the Table view (the buttons on the lower right) and create a **Relationship** between the two entities.
This will link them together. You will need an inverse so each entity knows about the other. If the `Category` can have one or more `Clothes` entities, you need to open the **Utility** pane on the right and set the relationship Type to **To Many**. This will then make your `clothes` relationship be an `NSSet`.

Comment: Thank you so much that really helped me!!